# Getting -- Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element -- working with Angular Materials 7.1.1 and Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the latest versions of Angular Materials and Angular.

I have followed this guide to install -> https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started.

I have tried this example -> https://stackblitz.com/angular/jamkkvgbkjkg?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.ts

I created the project using Visual Studio Code.

Everything is straight forward but the controls do not render.

I'm getting the error:
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element

https://github.com/jarninjanas/stackoverflow.git

Comment: Don't upload the node_modules folder next time. The whole point of npm is to get this folder downloaded from npm by *npm install* using package.json file

Comment: Another thing, next time it would be match better if you copy the error you're getting from the console of the browser so we could see the problem. This way you'll get more help.

Comment: The error you're getting in this case is: *Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-form-field' is not a known element*

Comment: Does this mean when I share my code, I delete node_modules?

Comment: You don't need to delete it, just don't add it to git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your linked project showed you're getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element

You've forgot to add `MatFormFieldModule` in your app.module.ts file.

**EDIT**: This is the point where you'll be facing another error:

> ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

When this time you've forgot to add `MatInputModule` to your app.module.ts file.

Comment: Thanks benshabatnoam. Solved my problem.